# Getting Attrbute error _exit_ when use "with" keyword

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have passed `.csv` file to post request,

```
input_file = data.get('file', None)
with input_file as datasheet:
        header = datasheet.readline()
```

Always I am getting error on second line. Also my file type is `Unicode` thats why it again giving error on third line for `readline()`

Comment: What's returned from `data.get()`?

Comment: {u'file': u'C:\\sample_datasheet.csv'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> with "test1.html" as fp:
...    header = fp.readline()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
>>>
```

How to Read file with **with** stament:

code:

```
>>> with open("test1.html") as fp:
...    header = fp.readline()
...
```

Check file is exits or not before doing any process.

Use os module

**Demo**:

```
>>> os.path.isfile("test1.html")
True
>>> os.path.isfile("nofile.html")
False
>>>
```

---

File Upload to server via post request in API testing using tastypie

```
fp = open("C:\sample_datasheet.csv", 'rb')
content = fp.read()
fp.close()

fd ={'file': "C:\sample_datasheet.csv", "content": content}
self.assertHttpOK(self.api_client.post('api of upload', format='json',\
org_id=2, content_type="multipart/form-data",\
data=fd))
```

and Save `content` from the `data` to server location in the view.

Comment: I had tried this but now giving error for third line unicode not having attribute readline()

Comment: what you are tring to do? means file in present on server and u r passing file name in url? correct??

Comment: file is present on my local machine and I am passing name in post data @viveksable

Comment: can you pass me py file and html and CSV file- on my email(vivekbsable@gmaill.com)

Comment: actually i m doing testing and while uploading a file in post request data this error occured. when i pass the file trough post data it received in type unicode format at api side and i am using .chunks() on that so it raises an error as Unicode object has no attribute chunks @viveksable

Comment: means you want to upload CSV file from the interface? or you want to pass only CSV file name ?

Comment: i want to pass csv file from interface @viveksable  can we talk in chats

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79506/discussion-between-sanket-and-vivek-sable).

Comment: so we need to 1. get file object from the request. 2. Save file data on server 3. Do our process. Can you check my answer again, I added save file code in it.

Comment: there is no file present in request.FILES @viveksable

Comment: <MultiValueDict: {}> is null @viveksable

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `{u'file': u'C:\\sample_datasheet.csv'}` is returned by the `data.get()` function, you have to obtain the file name and open it:

```
data = data.get('file', None)
fname = data["file"]
with open(fname, "r") as datasheet:
        header = datasheet.readline()
```

Comment: but raising another error as         
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'chunks'.  when i am doing "for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():  " uploaded file is the same input_file @dlask

Comment: can we upload a file through post in test case using tastypie @dlask

Comment: Please check carefully the type of every piece of data you are dealing with. It is not possible to use a dictionary where a file object is expected, it is not possible to use a number where file name is expected, and so on.

Comment: what is the answer of second can we upload a file throgh post request in tastypie @dlask

Comment: @Sanket I suppose it's your turn now. Add several `print` statements to your code, look what's in individual variables, check the documentation what can be done with such variables, and find the right shape of your code.

Comment: its ok @dlask, i have tried with "print" statements also , when i post file it receives as type Unicode in api thats why error occur. we cannot use chunks on Unicode . any other solution ???   Thank you